# How to shift several rows in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have the following pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'one' : pd.Series([1.], index=['a']), 'two' : pd.Series([1., 2.], index=['a', 'b']), 'three' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[["one", "two", "three"]]


   one  two  three
a  1.0  1.0    1.0
b  NaN  2.0    2.0
c  NaN  NaN    3.0
d  NaN  NaN    4.0
```

I know how to shift elements by column upwards/downwards, e.g.

```
df.two = df.two.shift(-1)

   one  two  three
a  1.0  2.0    1.0
b  NaN  NaN    2.0
c  NaN  NaN    3.0
d  NaN  NaN    4.0
```

However, I would like to shift all elements in row `a` over two columns and all elements in row `b` over one column. The final data frame would look like this:

```
   one  two  three
a  NaN  NaN    1.0
b  NaN  NaN    2.0
c  NaN  NaN    3.0
d  NaN  NaN    4.0
```

How does one do this in pandas?

Comment: We don't need to transpose the DF, just choose the `axis` parameter in the `shift`. Look my answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can transpose the initial `DF` so that you have a way to access the row labels as column names inorder to perform the [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) operation.

Shift the contents of the respective columns downward by those amounts and re-transpose it back to get the desired result.

```
df_t = df.T
df_t.assign(a=df_t['a'].shift(2), b=df_t['b'].shift(1)).T
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! I think we can even improve it a bit - `.shift()` accepts `axis` parameter: `df.assign(one=df[['one']].shift(2, axis=1), two=df[['two']].shift(1, axis=1))`

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a good suggestion. But then, won't the amount with which it gets shifted have no influence on the outcome as we're merely selecting a single columned `DF` and performing shift across columns?

Comment: Try for this case - `df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), list('abcd'), ['one','two','three'])`, you'll understand what I mean. Moreover, the OP wants just the first two rows to be modifed :-)

Comment: yep, i got it now. Thank you for the explanation! I can't upvote your answer the second time though ;-)

Comment: This is a new question, but I'm curious: Instead of just `a=df_t['a'].shift(2), b=df_t['b'].shift(1)`, what if there were multiple columns in need of shifting? Like columns `a` though `z` in need of shifting 2, columns 20 through 100 in need of shifting 5, etc.?

Comment: Then, something like - `df_t.loc[:, "a":"z"] = df_t.loc[:, "a":"z"].shift(2)` would make it happen for you. Don't forget to transpose the `DF` back.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, this is a more pythonic way:

```
df.loc['a'] = df.loc['a'].shift(periods=2,axis=0)
```

Note in this case `.loc` returns a Series, so `axis=0` is optional.