# How to use previous N values in pandas column to fill NaNs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a time series data as below.

```
 df
       priceA    priceB
  0     25.67    30.56
  1     34.12    28.43
  2     37.14    29.08
  3     Nan       34.23
  4     32          Nan
  5     18.75    41.1
  6     Nan       45.12
  7     23          39.67
  8     Nan       36.45
  9      36         Nan
```

Now I want to fill NaNs in column **priceA** by taking mean of previous N values in the column. In this case take N=3.
And for column **priceB** I have to fill Nan by value M rows above(current index-M).

I tried to write for loop for it which is not a good practice as my data is too large. Is there a better way to do this?

```
N=3
M=2
def fillPriceA( df,indexval,n):
      temp=[ ]
      for i in range(n):
          if i < 0:
                continue
          temp.append(df.loc[indexval-(i+1), 'priceA'])

      return np.nanmean(np.array(temp, dtype=np.float))

def fillPriceB(df,  indexval, m):
        return df.loc[indexval-m, 'priceB']

for idx, rows for df.iterrows():
         if idx< N: 
               continue
         else:
                if rows['priceA']==None:
                     rows['priceA']= fillPriceA(df, idx,N)
                if rows['priceB']==None:
                     rows['priceB']=fillPrriceB(df,idx,M)
```

Expected output:

```
        priceA      priceB
0      25.67        30.56
1      34.12        28.43
2      37.14        29.08
3      32.31        34.23
4      32             29.08
5      18.75       41.1
6       27.68      45.12
7       23            39.67
8       23.14      36.45
9       36            39.67
```

Comment: Would it be practical to transpose the values matrix to allow you to operate on columns instead of rows? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732565/how-to-shift-several-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe) suggests it might be a practical way to proceed, but you'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to only work with the `nan` index (see [dataframe boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)):

```
param = dict(priceA = 3, priceB = 2) #Number of previous values to consider

for col in df.columns:
    for i in df[np.isnan(df[col])].index: #Iterate over nan index 
        _window = df.iloc[max(0,(i-param[col])):i][col] #get the nth expected elements
        df.loc[i][col] = _window.mean() if col == 'priceA' else _window.iloc[0] #Replace with right method

print(df)
```

Result:

```
      priceA  priceB
0  25.670000   30.56
1  34.120000   28.43
2  37.140000   29.08
3  32.310000   34.23
4  32.000000   29.08
5  18.750000   41.10
6  27.686667   45.12
7  23.000000   39.67
8  23.145556   36.45
9  36.000000   39.67
```

---

**Note**
**1.** Using `np.isnan()` implies that your columns are numeric. If not convert your columns before with `pd.to_numeric()`:

```
...
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors = 'coerce')
    ...
```

Or use `pd.isnull()` instead (see example below). Be aware of the performances (`numpy` is faster):

```
from random import randint

#A sample with 10k elements and some np.nan
arr = np.random.rand(10000)
for i in range(100):
    arr[randint(0,9999)] = np.nan

#Performances
%timeit pd.isnull(arr)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.8 µs per loop

%timeit np.isnan(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.6 µs per loop
```

**2.** A more generic alternative could be to define methods and window size to apply for each column in a `dict`:

```
import pandas as pd

param = {}
param['priceA'] = {'n':3,
                   'method':lambda x: pd.isnull(x)}

param['priceB'] = {'n':2,
                   'method':lambda x: x[0]}
```

`param` contains now `n` the number of elements and `method` a lambda expression. Accordingly rewrite your loops:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for i in df[np.isnan(df[col])].index: #Iterate over nan index 
        _window = df.iloc[max(0,(i-param[col]['n'])):i][col] #get the nth expected elements
        df.loc[i][col] = param[col]['method'](_window.values) #Replace with right method

print(df)#This leads to a similar result.
```

Comment: I tried your 1st solution but it gives an error on line `for i in df[np.isnan(df[col])].index`
 `TypeError: ufunc isnan not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to casting rule `

Comment: Seems that your `df[col].dtype` is not  numeric (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001191/3941704). Can you try to convert it using `pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors = 'coerce')`, or replace `np.isnan` by `pd.isnull`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an NA mask to do what you need per column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4, None, 5, 6], 'b': [1, None, 2, 3, 4, None, 7]})
df

#     a b
# 0 1.0 1.0
# 1 2.0 NaN
# 2 3.0 2.0
# 3 4.0 3.0
# 4 NaN 4.0
# 5 5.0 NaN
# 6 6.0 7.0

for col in df.columns:
    s = df[col]
    na_indices = s[s.isnull()].index.tolist()
    prev = 0
    for k in na_indices:
        s[k] = np.mean(s[prev:k])
        prev = k

    df[col] = s

print(df)

    a   b
# 0 1.0 1.0
# 1 2.0 1.0
# 2 3.0 2.0
# 3 4.0 3.0
# 4 2.5 4.0
# 5 5.0 2.5
# 6 6.0 7.0
```

While this is still a custom operation, I am pretty sure it will be slightly faster because it is not iterating over each row, just over the NA values, which I am assuming will be sparse compared to the actual data

Answer (score 0):

To fill priceA use `rolling`, then `shift` and use this result in `fillna`,

```
# make some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'priceA': range(10)})

#make some rows missing
df.loc[[4, 6], 'priceA'] = np.nan

n = 3

df.priceA = df.priceA.fillna(df.priceA.rolling(n, min_periods=1).mean().shift(1))
```

The only edge case here is when two nans are within `n` of one another but it seems to handle this as in your question.

For priceB just use `shift`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'priceB': range(10)})
df.loc[[4, 8], 'priceB'] = np.nan

m = 2

df.priceB = df.priceB.fillna(df.priceB.shift(m))
```

Like before, there is the edge case where there is a nan exactly `m` before another nan.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I assumed that. That's why I mentioned the edge cases. Try adding to your question to tell us what to do in these cases. Otherwise this answer solves the problem stated in your question.